# Ajax and internet explorer

Tags: php, javascript, xml, ajax

I have a piece of JavaScript code with an ajax request that prints out the contents of an XML file that won't work in IE8.
I came across some suggestions when I googled this problem and I've tried those that seemed relevant to what I was trying to do. I added the following line to my .htaccess file: AddType application/xml .xml .rss; I added overridemimetype to my code and I included the following line at the beginning of my xml file: header('Content-type: text/xml'). None of these have made any difference to the output in IE8 but adding the content type line to the XML file stopped it working in Firefox. I thought I must be misunderstanding something about the content type line so I tried including it in the php file that creates the XML file. When I put it at the beginning of the PHP file I got this warning: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent. I tried putting at the beginning of the function that creates the XML file but that didn't have any effect.  The code I'm using is below

```
<html>
<head>
<body>

    <script type ="text/javascript">

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else // 
        {
            xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        if (xhttp.overrideMimeType)
            xhttp.overrideMimeType('text/xml')


        xhttp.open("GET","captions_7.xml",false);
        xhttp.send();
        xmlDoc=xhttp.responseXML;
        if(xmlDoc)
        {
            document.write("ok");
            //in ie ok prints

        }
        else
        {
            document.write("failed");
        }

        elements = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("p");
        length = elements.length;

        for (var i=0; i<length ; i++)
        {
            //caption text
            document.write(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br />");
            //start time
            document.write(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].getAttribute("begin")+ "<br />");
            //end time
            document.write(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].getAttribute("end")+ "<br />");
        }


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

In IE8 the only output from this file is OK. In Firefox, Opera and Chrome, the contents of the XML file are displayed. I've checked the XML file in a validator and it reported no errors, so I don't think that's the problem. I would really appreciate it if anyone knows of a solution to this or has any suggestions as to what I could try.

In case it's important, this is the function that creates the xml file:

```
function createXML($referenceId){
header('Content-type: text/xml');
$content_id = $referenceId;
$XMLStart="<tt xml:lang=\"en\"><head><layout/></head><body><div xml:id=\"captions\">";
$XMLEnd = "</div></body></tt>";

$text;


$captionQuery = "SELECT caption_text, start_time, end_time FROM captions WHERE content_id = $content_id ORDER BY start_time ASC;";

$captionResult = mysql_query($captionQuery);


if(mysql_num_rows($captionResult)){

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($captionResult)){


        $text.="<p begin=\"".$row[start_time]."\" end=\"".$row[end_time]."\">".$row[caption_text]."</p>";

         }
}//end if

$XMLString = $XMLStart.$text.$XMLEnd;

$captionsFile="captions_".$content_id.".xml";
$captionsFileHandle = fopen($captionsFile, w) or die("can't open file");
fwrite($captionsFileHandle, $XMLString);
fclose($captionsFileHandle);
return $captionsFile;  

}
```

I'm very new to all this so apologies if this is a very stupid question. I assume this must be done everyday many thousands of times but I just can't see what I can do to fix it.

Comment: A quick hint: Have you checked for whitespaces chars before and after the php script you use to serve the xml? Doesn't invalidate the xml sent but hinder the chance to send the header

Comment: IE caches GET requests very agressively.  Unless you add the timestamp or something unique to the query string or use POST, it's likely that IE will not return updated data.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using jQuery's AJAX function; it's cross-browser compatible, so it should help clear up the issue.

Comment: @Eineki-Thanks for the tip, I'll look into doing that. @tandu - I'm not sure how to go about doing that, but I'll see what I can find out - thanks for the response.

Comment: I came across a couple of references to jQuery when I was googling this problem, but I've never used it and don't know anything about it.I'm under a bit of time pressure to get this sorted as it's a college assignment but I'll look into seeing if it's something I can learn quickly. Many thanks for the response.

Comment: No problem; jQuery is almost too simple to use.  Just download the JS source, attach it to your doc; and then use the basic jquery .ajax function to run it through.  I think it's only 3-4 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP function is doing this:  creating an xml file (an actual file) which it writes to disk.  returning the name of that file.

What you need to do is:  build a string of all the XML you want to send to the client,   echo that string

So:

Delete:

```
$captionsFile="captions_".$content_id.".xml";
$captionsFileHandle = fopen($captionsFile, w) or die("can't open file");
fwrite($captionsFileHandle, $XMLString);
fclose($captionsFileHandle);
return $captionsFile;
```

And replace it with

```
echo $XMLString;
```

This problem likely has nothing to do with whether or not you use jquery.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I can't do this though because what I'm ultimately trying to do is output the xml elements one at a time in response to time events from a video player-the code here is just test code I wrote because it's quicker than testing the whole application. Sorry, that's my bad, I should have been more clear in my question. Thanks again.